# Expo application (apk, aab) crashes in Wifi connection

Tags: react-native, build, expo, eas

I have a crash problem with my apk built with eas.

My app just hangs at splash screen,

I tried to read the log with adb logcat, I have nothing like

after several debugging attempts, i noticed that if the device is connected to a mobile network, the app launches without issue for the first time after generating my apk or aab

On the other hand, if the device is connected to a wifi network, that's where the app hangs, like it can't download the JS bundle, I also assume that's why I don't see any error message in my logs. .

Does anyone encounter the same problem? or can anyone help with this?

I use "expo": "~48.0.15"

Thank you Hello everyone!